# Use variable from outer function from inside inner function

Tags: c++

My code that contains function inside another function as shown below:

```
ReturnType OuterFunction(someParameters, MyType* mt)
{
   function<OtherType*(parameterList)> innerFunction = 
   [this](parameterList)
   {
      return someOtherFunction(someParameters, mt);
   }
}
```

I have added a parameter `MyType` to `someOtherFunction` and modified it's call as seen in above code.

`mt` is the variable that is passed from `OuterFunction` and I am not able to use it inside `someOtherFunction`.

It is giving me an error

> An enclosing-function local variable cannot be referenced in a lambda body unless if it is in the capture list.

Comment: You might want to learn more about [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and its [capture list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `mt` to your capture list in the lambda youre trying to use there.

By default you have no access to outside variables. And adding `this` is adding a Pointer to your object.

```c
ReturnType OuterFunction(T s1, K s2, MyType* mt)
{
   function<OtherType*(parameterList)> innerFunction = 
   [s1,s2,mt](parameterList)
   {
      return someOtherFunction(s1, s2, mt);
   }
}
```

You can take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp?view=vs-2019

Comment: `[this]` adds a **pointer** to the current object; this can be a very important difference when considering lifetimes; if the lambda is going to live longer than the object then it will keep referring to the dead thus summoning the undefined behavior nasal daemons.